# react-bootstrap positioning of control elements in table header

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I would like to create a react-bootstrap table with some control elements in the header and I am having trouble getting them to position correctly. Schematically, this is what I'm trying to do:

```html
<th>
  <div>Some Title</div>
  <Button>B1</Button>
  <InputGroup className="flex-nowrap" size="sm">
    <Button>B2</Button>
    <Button>B3</Button>
    <FormControl className="smallInput"/>
  </InputGroup>
</th>
```

The buttons B1, B2 and B3 should always have their natural width and the FormControl should have a pre-defined width of 3em. I do the latter with the following css:

```css
.smallInput {
    flex-grow: 0 !important;
    flex-basis: 3em !important;
}
```

The full code example is at https://codesandbox.io/s/table-with-controls-xkn1g?file=/src/App.js

I want to position the controls on the right side of the header. They should always be as small as they possibly can be and leave the rest of the space for the title.

I have experimented with various combinations of `Container`, `Row`, `Col`, `div` and CSS classes like `w-auto`, `d-flex`, `d-inline-block` etc. but I can't get the positioning right. Either the controls use up more space then they need to or they get wrapped in various unappealing ways.

I am fairly new to all of React/Bootstrap/CSS, so I'm not really sure what the right approach is here. I've been trying to convince the title div and the controls to use the minimum amount of width possible without wrapping and then use flex-box functionality to push the title div to the left and the rest to the right. Is that even the right way to go about it?

Comment: add sample in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Added a minimal example at https://codesandbox.io/s/table-with-controls-xkn1g?file=/src/App.js

Comment: no find sample in this link

Comment: possibly didn't save the code. Try again now?

Comment: Please include your ideal sample image